# "yield from iterable" vs "return iter(iterable)"

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable, yield-from

When wrapping an (internal) iterator one often has to reroute the `__iter__` method to the underlying iterable. Consider the following example:

```
class FancyNewClass(collections.Iterable):
    def __init__(self):
        self._internal_iterable = [1,2,3,4,5]

    # ...

    # variant A
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._internal_iterable)

    # variant B
    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self._internal_iterable
```

Is there any significant difference between variant A and B?
Variant A returns an iterator object that has been queried via `iter()` from the internal iterable. Variant B returns a generator object that returns values from  the internal iterable. Is one or the other preferable for some reason? In `collections.abc` the `yield from` version is used. The `return iter()` variant is the pattern that I have used until now.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The only significant difference is what happens when an exception is raised from within the iterable. Using `return iter()` your `FancyNewClass` will not appear on the exception traceback, whereas with `yield from` it will. It is generally a good thing to have as much information on the traceback as possible, although there could be situations where you want to hide your wrapper.

Other differences:

- `return iter` has to load the name `iter` from globals - this is potentially slow (although unlikely to significantly affect performance) and could be messed with (although anyone who overwrites globals like that deserves what they get).
- With `yield from` you can insert other `yield` expressions before and after (although you could equally use `itertools.chain`).
- As presented, the `yield from` form discards any generator return value (i.e. `raise StopException(value)`. You can fix this by writing instead `return (yield from iterator)`.

Here's a test comparing the disassembly of the two approaches and also showing exception tracebacks: http://ideone.com/1YVcSe

Using `return iter()`:

```
  3           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (iter)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (it)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 12, in test
  File "./prog.py", line 10, in i
RuntimeError
```

Using `return (yield from)`:

```
  5           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (it)
              3 GET_ITER
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              7 YIELD_FROM
              8 RETURN_VALUE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 12, in test
  File "./prog.py", line 5, in bar
  File "./prog.py", line 10, in i
RuntimeError
```

Comment: Assuming the goal is to simply transfer/expose the underlying iterable, i.e. no modification/injection of other items, I think I will stick with `iter()` because: 1) if I do not add any additional behavior, I do not need it to appear on the exception traceback (I think?). 2) to avoid using the global `iter()` I could call `return internal_iterable.__iter__()`.
Regarding the third point you raised, I'll have to think about what that means.