# yield from vs yield in for-loop

Tags: python, generator, yield, python-internals, yield-from

My understanding of `yield from` is that it is similar to `yield`ing every item from an iterable. Yet, I observe the different behavior in the following example.

I have `Class1`

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self, gen):
        self.gen = gen
        
    def __iter__(self):
        for el in self.gen:
            yield el
```

and Class2 that different only in replacing `yield` in for loop with `yield from`

```
class Class2:
    def __init__(self, gen):
        self.gen = gen
        
    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self.gen
```

The code below reads the first element from an instance of a given class and then reads the rest in a for loop:

```
a = Class1((i for i in range(3)))
print(next(iter(a)))
for el in iter(a):
    print(el)
```

This produces different outputs for `Class1` and `Class2`. For `Class1` the output is

```
0
1
2
```

and for `Class2` the output is

```
0
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sjb54zcTx)

What is the mechanism behind `yield from` that produces different behavior?

Comment: Not specifically an answer to your question, but https://stackoverflow.com/a/26109157/3216427 provides more ways in which yield from is different from a loop over yield.

Comment: Very weirdly enough, with `Class2`, if you extract `iter(a)` into a variable (`b = iter(a); print(next(b))`), this will work the same as `Class1`, i.e. prints all the numbers. That's confusing and very interesting.

Comment: Yep, and if you do `del b`, it only prints the first one @YevhenKuzmovych

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych There are too many bogus issues already, better ask at [discuss](https://discuss.python.org/) "Python Help" instead.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### What Happened?

When you use `next(iter(instance_of_Class2))`, `iter()` calls `.close()` on the inner generator when it (the iterator, not the generator!) goes out of scope (and is deleted), while with `Class1`, `iter()` only closes its instance

```py
>>> g = (i for i in range(3))
>>> b = Class2(g)
>>> i = iter(b)     # hold iterator open
>>> next(i)
0
>>> next(i)
1
>>> del(i)          # closes g
>>> next(iter(b))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

This behavior is described in PEP 342 in two parts

- [the new `.close()` method](https://peps.python.org/pep-0342/#new-generator-method-close) (well, new to Python 2.5)
- from the [Specification Summary](https://peps.python.org/pep-0342/#specification-summary)

  > 5. Add support to ensure that close() is called when a generator iterator is garbage-collected.

What happens is a little clearer (if perhaps surprising) when multiple generator delegations occur; only the generator being delegated is closed when its wrapping `iter` is deleted

```py
>>> g1 = (a for a in range(10))
>>> g2 = (a for a in range(10, 20))
>>> def test3():
...     yield from g1
...     yield from g2
... 
>>> next(test3())
0
>>> next(test3())
10
>>> next(test3())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

---

#### Fixing `Class2`

What options are there to make `Class2` behave more the way you expect?

Notably, other strategies, though they don't have the visually pleasing [sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) of `yield from` or some of its [potential benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59600668/4541045) gives you a way to interact with the values, which seems like a primary benefit

- avoid creating a structure like this at all ("just don't do that!")
  if you don't interact with the generator and don't intend to keep a reference to the iterator, why bother wrapping it at all? (see above comment about interacting)
- create the iterator yourself internally (this may be what you expected)

  ```py
  >>> class Class3:
  ...     def __init__(self, gen):
  ...         self.iterator = iter(gen)
  ...         
  ...     def __iter__(self):
  ...         return self.iterator
  ... 
  >>> c = Class3((i for i in range(3)))
  >>> next(iter(c))
  0
  >>> next(iter(c))
  1
  ```
- make the whole class a "proper" Generator
  while testing this, it plausibly highlights some `iter()` inconsistency - see comments below (ie. why isn't `e` closed?)
  also an opportunity to pass multiple generators with `itertools.chain.from_iterable`

  ```py
  >>> class Class5(collections.abc.Generator):
  ...     def __init__(self, gen):
  ...         self.gen = gen
  ...     def send(self, value):
  ...         return next(self.gen)
  ...     def throw(self, value):
  ...         raise StopIteration
  ...     def close(self):          # optional, but more complete
  ...         self.gen.close()
  ... 
  >>> e = Class5((i for i in range(10)))
  >>> next(e)        # NOTE iter is not necessary!
  0
  >>> next(e)
  1
  >>> next(iter(e))  # but still works
  2
  >>> next(iter(e))  # doesn't close e?? (should it?)
  3
  >>> e.close()
  >>> next(e)
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/_collections_abc.py", line 330, in __next__
      return self.send(None)
    File "<stdin>", line 5, in send
  StopIteration
  ```

---

#### Hunting the Mystery

A better clue is that if you directly try again, `next(iter(instance))` raises `StopIteration`, indicating the generator is permanently closed (either through exhaustion or `.close()`), and why iterating over it with a `for` loop yields no more values

```py
>>> a = Class1((i for i in range(3)))
>>> next(iter(a))
0
>>> next(iter(a))
1
>>> b = Class2((i for i in range(3)))
>>> next(iter(b))
0
>>> next(iter(b))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

However, if we name the iterator, it works as expected

```py
>>> b = Class2((i for i in range(3)))
>>> i = iter(b)
>>> next(i)
0
>>> next(i)
1
>>> j = iter(b)
>>> next(j)
2
>>> next(i)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

To me, this suggests that when the iterator doesn't have a name, it calls `.close()` when it goes out of scope

```py
>>> def gen_test(iterable):
...     yield from iterable
... 
>>> g = gen_test((i for i in range(3)))
>>> next(iter(g))
0
>>> g.close()
>>> next(iter(g))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Disassembling the result, we find the internals are a little different

```py
>>> a = Class1((i for i in range(3)))
>>> dis.dis(a.__iter__)
  6           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              2 LOAD_ATTR                0 (gen)
              4 GET_ITER
        >>    6 FOR_ITER                10 (to 18)
              8 STORE_FAST               1 (el)

  7          10 LOAD_FAST                1 (el)
             12 YIELD_VALUE
             14 POP_TOP
             16 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6
        >>   18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
>>> b = Class2((i for i in range(3)))
>>> dis.dis(b.__iter__)
  6           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              2 LOAD_ATTR                0 (gen)
              4 GET_YIELD_FROM_ITER
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 
             10 POP_TOP
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

Notably, the `yield from` version has [`GET_YIELD_FROM_ITER`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-GET_YIELD_FROM_ITER)

> If `TOS` is a generator iterator or coroutine object it is left as is. Otherwise, implements `TOS = iter(TOS)`.

(subtly, `YIELD_FROM` keyword appears to be removed in 3.11)

So if the given iterable (to the class) *is* a generator iterator, it'll be handed off directly, giving the result we (might) expect

---

#### Extras

Passing an iterator which isn't a generator (`iter()` creates a new iterator each time in both cases)

```py
>>> a = Class1([i for i in range(3)])
>>> next(iter(a))
0
>>> next(iter(a))
0
>>> b = Class2([i for i in range(3)])
>>> next(iter(b))
0
>>> next(iter(b))
0
```

Expressly closing `Class1`'s internal generator

```py
>>> g = (i for i in range(3))
>>> a = Class1(g)
>>> next(iter(a))
0
>>> next(iter(a))
1
>>> a.gen.close()
>>> next(iter(a))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

generator is only closed by `iter` when deleted if instance is popped

```py
>>> g = (i for i in range(10))
>>> b = Class2(g)
>>> i = iter(b)
>>> next(i)
0
>>> j = iter(b)
>>> del(j)        # next() not called on j
>>> next(i)
1
>>> j = iter(b)
>>> next(j)
2
>>> del(j)        # generator closed
>>> next(i)       # now fails, despite range(10) above
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Comment: You can also look at [the PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0380/#formal-semantics), you can see the `close` call there.

Comment: That's explanatory, but still fairly opaque as to _why_! .. but from that, PEP 342 looks like it brings both [the new close method](https://peps.python.org/pep-0342/#new-generator-method-close) and sneaks in [5. Add support to ensure that `close()` is called when a generator iterator is garbage-collected.](https://peps.python.org/pep-0342/#specification-summary)

Comment: @ti7 Why is the generator iterator garbage collected if it’s still referenced by self.gen?

Comment: it's not that there's no leftover reference (there is, which is how it raises `StopIteration` rather than `AttributeError` or `NameError`, etc.), rather it happens when `iter()`' is collected and explicitly calls `.close()` on the generator it's wrapping

Comment: This is just my subjective opinion, but this feels like a bug even though it's in accordance with the spec. If the spec mandates this then I would say the spec mandates the wrong behaviour. That said, I am not 100% sure that the spec does mandate this behaviour, because it depends on when an object is garbage-collected, and as far as I know the spec doesn't say exactly when that should happen. It should be consistent with the spec to delay garbage-collection until the generator is exhausted in the normal way.

Comment: it's hard for me to pick a side - honestly, I'm mostly in the "don't do this" camp, even if this turns out to be a decade-old bug.. the behavior should almost-certainly be more consistent here, but perhaps `iter(generator)` should `raise RuntimeError` and/or `yield from` (or simply `yield`) should raise `SyntaxError` in some reserved dunder methods, forcing `return` and preferring `next()` (or `await`) internally! PEP 525 for Asynchronous Generators also hints usefulness imo by not even implementing delegation and suggesting `async for` https://peps.python.org/pep-0525/#asynchronous-yield-from

Answer (score 2):

**updated**

I don't see it as that complicated, and the resulting behavior can be seen as actually unsurprising.

When the iterator goes out of scope, Python will throw a "GeneratorExit" exception in the (innermost) generator.

On the "classic" `for` form, the exception happens in the user-written `__iter__` method, is not catch, and is suppressed when bubbling up by the generator mechanisms.

On the `yield from` form, the same exception is thrown in the inner `self.gen`, thus "killing" it, and bubbles up to the user-written `__iter__` .

Writing another intermediate generator can make this easily visible:

```
def inner_gen(gen):
    try:
        for item in gen:
            yield item
    except GeneratorExit:
        print("Generator exit thrown in inner generator")

class Class1:
    def __init__(self, gen):
        self.gen = inner_gen(gen)
        
    def __iter__(self):
        try:
            for el in self.gen:
                yield el
        except GeneratorExit:
            print("Generator exit thrown in outer generator for 'classic' form")
            
    
class Class2(Class1):
    def __iter__(self):
        try:
            yield from self.gen
        except GeneratorExit as exit:
            print("Generator exit thrown in outer generator for 'yield from' form" )
        
first = lambda g:next(iter(g))
```

And now:

```
In [324]: c1 = Class1((i for i in range(2)))

In [325]: first(c1)
Generator exit thrown in outer generator for 'classic' form
Out[325]: 0

In [326]: first(c1)
Generator exit thrown in outer generator for 'classic' form
Out[326]: 1

In [327]: c2 = Class2((i for i in range(2)))

In [328]: first(c2)
Generator exit thrown in inner generator
Generator exit thrown in outter generator for 'yield from' form
Out[328]: 0

In [329]: first(c2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[329], line 1
(...)

StopIteration:
```

**update**
I had a previous answer text speculating how the call to `close` would take place, skipping the intermediate generator - it is not that simple regarding `close` though: Python will always call `__del__` - not `close`, which is only called by the user, or in certain circunstances that were hard to pin down. But it will always throw the `GeneratorExit` exception in a generator-function body (not in a class with explict `__next__` and `throw` , though - let's skip this for another question :-D )

Comment: Excellent simple explanation, thank you for that!

Comment: despite my answer here being text only, I did made some tests on an interactive environment. I will replicate then and paste the snippets here. (it is possible that I did not explicitly testes for this bypassing but I will do so now).

Comment: Testing this stuff correctly is even more intricate :-)  and it does not seem to "fit in mind all at once" - but the final finding can be even simpler: Python throws a `GeneratorExit` in the innermost generator when it goes out of scope and let it propagate. In the "for" form, this is in the user-written `__iter__` method,

Comment: @joanis : it ended up being even simpler, but I had to completely rewrite it.

Comment: I've added the code I used to check calls for `__del__` and `__close__` in each case here: https://gist.github.com/jsbueno/e4378521ead8f9dbb40565fb5cacd0b9